# Subqueries do not work in Windows, but works on Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, mariadb

I am finding something in MariaDB and I don't know how to investigate or fix. It only happens on Windows. MariaDB on Linux and MySQL on windows both work well. Possibly / likely I am doing something obviously wrong but I am intrigued.

I tried to reproduce in a simple table to provide more info but it actually works so i can't reproduce. Surely something else is influencing the behavior but I don't know what.

The issue: **subquery with IN does not work.** Here's the overall query:

```
Select table1.entityKey
from table1 
where table1.Deleted = 0 
and table1.MasterKey is null 
and table1.entityTypeKey = 8 
and table1.entityKey in 
   (select table2.entityKey 
    from table2 
    where table2.Flag <> 2 
    and (table2.IndexKey = 4 and MATCH (table2.xhtmltext) AGAINST ('gold'))) 
order by table1.entityKey DESC
```

For my dataset, this should return values 2 and 3, but gives an empty set.

So I split the queries and I find this: 
The subquery correctly returns 2, 3 and 4,

```
select table2.entityKey 
  from table2 
  where table2.Flag <> 2 
  and (table2.IndexKey = 4 and MATCH (table2.xhtmltext) AGAINST ('gold'))
```

If I pass these values to the outer query, it correctly filters out the 4, and gives me the correct result (2,3):

```
Select table1.entityKey
from table1 
where table1.Deleted = 0 
and table1.MasterKey is null 
and table1.entityTypeKey = 8 
and table1.entityKey in 
   (2,3,4) 
order by table1.entityKey DESC
```

What could be wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: If a subquery and an outer query separately return correct results, but their combination does not, it's an indication of a bug. Please report it at https://jira.mariadb.org . For the Windows/Linux difference, most likely you have different MariaDB versions on Linux and Windows, and one of them has a bug while another one does not. Compare the output of `SELECT @@version` on each server. Another possible reason is that server settings are different and, again, one of configurations reveals a bug. If the version is the same, compare the output of `SHOW VARIABLES` (ignore paths and such).

Comment: MyISAM?  InnoDB?  Same on both systems?

Comment: This seems indeed to be a bug in versions 10.2 and above. Will do some more tests and report an issue.

Comment: As a workaround, you can set `optimizer_switch=orderby_uses_equalities=off` in the config file, it should help

Answer (score 0):

It is usually best to avoid `IN ( SELECT ... )` where practical.  Your case is easy to transform:

```
Select  table1.entityKey
    from  table1
    JOIN  table2  USING(entityKey)
    where  table1.Deleted = 0
      and  table1.MasterKey is null
      and  table1.entityTypeKey = 8
      and  table2.Flag <> 2
      and  table2.IndexKey = 4
      and  MATCH (table2.xhtmltext) AGAINST ('gold'))
    order by  table1.entityKey DESC
```

If that does not work, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` from both machines.  Also `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who encounter this, this is indeed a bug: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13704